# How to draw x axis and y-axis origin line draw in ng2-google-charts?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, google-visualization

```
options: {
        height: '100%', width: '90%', backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true,
            trigger: 'selection'
        },
        hAxis: { textPosition: 'none', logscale: true  },
        chartArea: {
            width: "78%",
            'backgroundColor': {
                'fill': '#ffffff',
                'opacity': 100
            },
        },
        vAxis: {
            textStyle: {
                fontSize: 13 // or the number you want
            },
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            },
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            },
            ticks: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100] // display labels every 25
        },
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        colors: ["orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange", "orange"]
    },
```

I used above options to hide grid lines but in my case i want to draw x-axis and y-axis origin line alone in column chart.

[image: above options graph]

x-axis is coming correct but in y-axis origin line i'm not able to draw.

can any one help me on this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried but it is drawing x-axis baseline not y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
hAxis: {
  baselineColor: 'black',
  ticks: []
},
vAxis: {
  baselineColor: 'black',
  ticks: []
}
```

The baseline for the hAxis is a vertical line and the baseline for the vAxis is a horizontal line. So if you want to remove the horizontal black line you need to set the vAxis baselineColor and vice-versa.